# Chrome IFRAME issue

Tags: html, iframe

Im trying to display an iframe within chrome, it works in IE and in FF.
When looking at the dev tools in Chrome the only issue I can see is the HTTP request showing as canceled.

The Chrome version is Version 28.0.1500.95 m

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="content">                 
    <iframe src ="https://mydomain.com/myotherpage/" width="100%" height="1250" frameborder="0">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone any idea on what could be causing this ?

Comment: Can you show the html?

Comment: What chrome version? What system? HTML code? You will get relevant/helpfu answer, only if you provide as much info as can(should).

Comment: Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12009423/447356) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11581760/447356)?

Comment: so iframe src is https. is your main page https? is the page you're trying to frame your own? is it on the same domain? does it send x-frame headers?

Comment: Does not work neither in IE nor in FF for me. [mydomain.com](http://mydomain.com) does not allow CORs.

Comment: Maybe it is related to X-Frame-Options header, as specified here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Comment: mydomain.com is not real just an example.
And yep its on the same domain :o)